# MaxListeners Exceeded when combining web3UIkit and React/Moralis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, moralis

I am continuously running into a MaxListeners Exceeded issue in my project and I cannot find the solution to it. The problem presents itself when browsing between pages in the navBar a few times and after a couple of clicks the console notifies the Maxlisteners issue. I find this weird as the coding is nothing special and I cannot find the rootcause of this.

I have created a seperate barebones project on Github that only has the minimum required packages on it to try and isolate the problem. It seems as though the web3UIKit, React, Moralis and/or Next don't play well with eachother however I lack the expertise to determine this 100%.

My question to you is: can you find the cause of this problem or do you know of a solution to counteract this problem all together.

I will share the code below and a GitHub close for your convenience. I will be forever in your debt if you can help me.

github clone: https://github.com/deAgora/maxlisteners.git

_app.js

```
import { MoralisProvider } from "react-moralis";
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <MoralisProvider initializeOnMount={false}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </MoralisProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Index.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Header></Header>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div>This page is an example to illustrate the maxlisteners issue</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Page1.js

```
import Head from "next/head";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <Header></Header>
      <Navbar></Navbar>
      <div>
        Page 1: This page is an example to illustrate the maxlisteners issue
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Component Header.js

```
import { ConnectButton } from "@web3uikit/web3";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="p-5 border-b-2 flex flex-row bg-slate-400">
      <h1 className="py-4 px-4 font-blog text-3xl">Maxlisteners Example</h1>
      <div className="ml-auto py-2 px-4">
        <ConnectButton moralisAuth={false}></ConnectButton>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Component: Navbar.js

```
import Link from "next/link";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-400">
      <ul className="grid grid-cols-3 place-items-center py-2 border-b-2 f">
        <li>
          <Link href="/">
            <a>Home</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link href="/page1">
            <a>Page1</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "maxlisteners",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@web3uikit/core": "^0.1.5",
    "@web3uikit/icons": "^0.1.5",
    "@web3uikit/web3": "^0.1.5",
    "magic-sdk": "^9.0.0",
    "moralis": "^2.0.3",
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-moralis": "^1.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you are trying to use [Moralis 2.0](https://docs.moralis.io/) (2.0.3) which won't work with react-moralis - this is a new SDK compared to the previous SDK (which is now called `moralis-v1`).

You will need to use these versions - `moralis@1.11.0` and `react-moralis@1.4.0` in your Next.js project as there is an issue with the latest moralis-v1 and react-moralis.

If you have more questions or issues with this, please post on either:

- Moralis Discord: https://moralis.io/joindiscord
- Moralis forum: https://forum.moralis.io

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for reaching out! I have implemented your suggestions (by downgrading the packages to your suggested versions) however this does not seem to make a difference. Have you tried your proposed solution i.e. can you get the above code to work without having the console throw errors?

Comment: Hi Patrick, I would suggest trying in a new project, and use npm to install everything if you have previously used yarn. Yes, I can use react-moralis@1.4.0 and moralis@1.11.0 together in a new Next.js (create-next-app) project. Other users have tried slightly older versions like react-moralis@1.3.5 and moralis@1.8.0 with success.